# Subscribe for first event occurence with cancellation using System.Reactive.Linq

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Given IObservable sequence made from event stream:

```
IObservable<MyEvent> observable = EventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>()
```

I get first event occurence:

```
MyEvent myEvent = await observable.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

However, **I want to dispose the subscription, resp. interrupt the observable when user clicks cancel button.**

currently I use workaround with .ToTask() extension method, but I believe there is cleaner solution based on Rective extension only.

```
_tsc = new CancellationTokenSource();
MyEvent myEvent;
try
{
    myEvent = await EventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>()
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
        .ToTask(__tsc.Token);
}
catch (TaskCanceledException)
{
    myEvent = null;
}


void Cancel()
{
    _tsc.Cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is very easy with the built-in Rx operators.

Just do this:

```
IObservable<MyEvent> observable = EventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>()
var endItAll = new Subject<Unit>();
MyEvent myEvent = await observable.TakeUntil(endItAll).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Now you can simply call `endItAll.OnNext(Unit.Default)` to end the subscription and return a `null` `MyEvent`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is "cleaner", but you can do that without `ToTask` like that:

```
static async void Test(IObservable<int> ob, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var first = await ob.TakeUntil(Observable.Create<Unit>(o => ct.Register(() => {
            o.OnNext(Unit.Default);
            o.OnCompleted();
    }))).FirstOrDefaultAsync();            
}
```

So we create another observable which will produce an element when cancellation token is cancelled, then we use `TakeUntil` overload which will return elements from first sequence until second sequence produces an element. So after you cancel the token - your `await` statement will return with default value (`null` for reference types).

You can move that to extension method, then it will look better:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static IObservable<T> TakeUntilCancelled<T>(this IObservable<T> ob, CancellationToken ct) {
        return ob.TakeUntil(Observable.Create<Unit>(o => ct.Register(() =>
        {
            o.OnNext(Unit.Default);
            o.OnCompleted();
        })));
    }
}

var first = await ob.TakeUntilCancelled(ct).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: Yep, I was looking for something like this. But the namig convention should be `TakeUntilNotCancelled`, shouldnt it?

Comment: Well english is not my native language, so not sure. Though default `TakeUntil` will take values from first until second produces element. In our case second produces element when token is cancelled. So from that logic I assumed it should be TakeUntilCancelled.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've mistaken TakeUntil and TakeWhile